# import variables from a text file and use it in an equation

Tags: python, variables, import, save

How I can import data from .txt and state them as my new variables? And each time save an output as a new text file with my input variables and the solution.

I have text file "values.txt" which includes of:

```
k=10
t=20
r=8.5
```

(separated by "enter")

and I also have python file in where is put the equation:
`a = k*t/r`

for now I've figured out only these:

```
txt = open("values.txt").read()
print(txt)    

a = k*t/r
print(a)

txt.close()
```

Comment: Is the input file format fixed? Why not just have three values on the same line?

Comment: @DYZ I was under the impression that the `values.txt` file was open for guidance on how to store the file, too.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer storing my `.txt` as a `json` file. My `filename` looking like :

```
{ "foo":
    "bar"
}
```

From here, you can have

```
import json
#Read JSON data into the datastore variable
if filename:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        datastore = json.load(f)

#Use the new datastore datastructure
print datastore["foo"]
```

Comment: A lot of great answers here. I believe JSON is the one that will offer the best guidance, as you can do matrices and the such with ease.

Comment: "don't reinvent the wheel" –I like it

Answer (score 3):

More generally you may create a dict variable_name:value to use in your equations.

For instance:

```
variables = {}

with open("values.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.split("=")
        variables[name] = float(value)

k = variables["k"] 
t = variables["t"] 
r = variables["r"] 

a = k*t/r
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Read the file. Separate by `\r\n`. Fetch the values by splitting on `=`

```
txt = open("values.txt").readLines()
k = float(txt[0].split("=")[0])
t = float(txt[1].split("=")[0])
r= float(txt[2].split("=")[0])
a = k*t/r
print(a)

txt.close()
```

This method is fine when dealing with less values otherwise use [csvreader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line in the file by iterating over it. You can then split each line by the `=` character.

```
constants = {}
with open('values.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, val = line.split('=')
        constants[name] = float(val)

>>> constants['a']
10.0
>>> constants['t']
20.0
>>> constants['r']
8.5
```

I've created a dictionary called `constants` which holds any number of `name : value` pairs as you like for each constant. Then all you need to do is amend your calculations to derive their values from the constants dictionary.

This allows you to add as many constants as you like: by not hard coding any variables, you add extensibility.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the format of the input file, make it as simple as possible. Put all three numbers on the same line (as in `10 20 8.5`) and read with:

```
with open("values.txt") as infile:
    k, t, r = map(float, infile.read().split())
```

Comment: This reduces readability in the .txt file and doesn't allow for extensibility.

Comment: It depends on the scale of the problem.

Comment: That's true, but I would have assumed that the OP has many constants to store and obviously separating them into another file makes it easier to read. A hard cider approach is definitely the quickest but as I said becomes cumbersome after adding more constants

Comment: @NChauhan One also should not use a tool more powerful than necessary. I can easily see when the vanilla approach wins: when the files with numbers are generated automatically and are not even intended for human eyes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very helpful